# React Router Dom chaining routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a button that routes to a different page on my website based on a `path` prop. So from the home page, the button can route to the About Me page using the `/about` path. However, if a button is clicked on the `/about` path, it tries going to a `/about/path` path instead of navigating to `/path`. Is there a way to fix this?

Button code (react component)

```js
interface Props {
  path: string;
  text: string;
}
const ButtonShift = ({ path, text }: Props) => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const routeChange = () => {
    navigate(path);
  };
  return (
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={routeChange}>
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ButtonShift;
```

Router code

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
    <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Your `ButtonShift` component is utterly correct. I think you should add a little bit more information about how you used the `ButtonShift`. Because your route configurations are correct too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using relative paths instead of absolute paths. Relative paths will append the path value to the end of the current URL path instead of replacing it.

Instead of

```
<ButtonShift path="projects" text="About" />
```

which might result in `"/about/projects"`, use

```
<ButtonShift path="/projects" text="About" />
```

This should result in navigating to `"/projects"`.

Comment: Phenomenal right, it is exactly why I asked him to add more information about his usage of `The ButtonShift` component.